# Does MAGMA use a standard p-modular system?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, magma

I'd like to ask the following question:

> Are the **Brauer character values** of $kG$-modules (where $k$ and $G$ are finite) in MAGMA computed with respect to the standard $p$-modular system described in the book of Lux and Pahlings* (chapter 4 in Representations of Groups: A computational Approach)?

Remark 1: I am asking this, because I would like to inflate Brauer characters from factor groups and then induce them to a common supergroup and I'd like to get consistent results.

Remark 2: I posted this question on math.stackexchange.com (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3239642/does-magma-use-a-standard-p-modular-system), but I got no answer and no comment.

Thank you very much for any help.

**Edit:**

*See pages 305-307 of https://books.google.de/books?id=VSZIBpYGwSMC&pg=PA315&lpg=PA315&dq=lux+pahlings+bruaer+characters&source=bl&ots=tjiXv1MYLC&sig=ACfU3U0HfCxHlCErPnMEnHRpxtwSEUccGw&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwif6uXzsc7iAhXB_KQKHX1cDWcQ6AEwDXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=lux%20pahlings%20bruaer%20characters&f=false

There, a bold $\mathbf{\zeta}_m$ denotes the complex number $e^{\frac{2\pi i}{m}}$. Often, $m=p^n-1$.

Comment: One reason you had no feedback on MathSE is possibly you didn't include any mathematical tag.

Comment: @YCor Thanks for the comment. To the tag magma-cas already being there I added some mathematical tags on MathSE.

Comment: Compare MAGMA https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=MAGMA&title=%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%3A%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA&go=%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8 and Magma https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(computer_algebra_system) BTW, my previous comment where the difference was explained was deleted by an unknown to me person.

Comment: @user64494 Your earlier comment linked to the Ukrainian Wikipedia here https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma where the article -- correct me if I'm wrong -- seems to be about a progressive rock group named MAGMA. In any case, a cursory examination of this site shows many users spelling the name of the algebra software as MAGMA, and therefore I find your edit of the orthography unnecessary. At a user's request, I am rolling back.

Comment: @user64494 The logo of the computer algebra system MAGMA is written in capital letters, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(computer_algebra_system) ...Moreover, in many papers it was written like this, so I also wrote it like this.

Comment: Up to the cited Russian Wiki, "MAGMA — open file format based on YAML intended to describe the file links to download the protocols of Gnutella, HTTP, FTP, etc". Also the MAGMA search in Google Chrome does not bring to the Magma CAS.

Comment: We must  listen to moderators so I cancel my edit.

Comment: My opinion is that although MAGMA is a correct spelling, the use of an entirely capitalized word, especially in a title, sounds a bit aggressive (and the aggression effect is proportional to the number of letters, so it's fortunate it's only 3 letters); this is particularly true for a proprietary software, which has a pecuniary interest in convincing its users to emphasize its name. I regret the edit has been canceled.

Comment: Sorry, it was not my intention to sound aggressive... I also would have written GAP instead of gap or Gap.

Comment: At least GAP does specify how their character values are computed - and you can inspect the corresponding source code if you must :P

Comment: @YCor In a case like this, where there is no mistake and obviously no aggression, the preferred spelling of the OP should be respected.

Comment: @YCor --- perhaps using _smallcaps_ might be a compromise? (not yet implemented in StackExchange, see this [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291259/could-we-have-smallcaps-formatting) , I faked _smallcaps_ in my answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Paragraph 3.2.1 of [On Certain Subgroups of $E_8(2)$ and their Brauer Character Tables](https://www.research.manchester.ac.uk/portal/files/84018931/FULL_TEXT.PDF) explains precisely how the Brauer characters are defined in <sup><sub>MAGMA</sub></sup>. The ambiguity in the definition refers to the choice of a definite root of unity. <sup><sub>MAGMA</sub></sup> uses Conway polynomials for that purpose and from [page 306](https://books.google.de/books?id=VSZIBpYGwSMC&pg=PA306&lpg=PA306) of Lux and Pahlings I gather that they use the same convention.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you happen to know, why in the MAGMA online manual (see https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/1052#11981) it is nevertheless written "Note that problems associated with choice of lifting from finite fields to complex roots of unity have not yet been dealt with." ?

Comment: I presume because the "roots of unity" ambiguity is only handled automatically by MAGMA when it knows the corresponding Conway polynomial, which is for $\exp[2\pi i/(p^n-1)]$ with $n$ up to 94.

Comment: Ok, that presumption sounds reasonable, thanks.